# Mounting HDD inside ${HOME} - is there any bad side effect?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Currently I have my 6TB HDD (ext4, single partition) mounted to `/mnt/mydisk` in my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. However, I would love to see it inside my home directory. So, if I mount the disk at `${HOME}/mydisk`, will it work? Is there any bad side effect if I do that? I was thinking,

- Unmount from `/mnt/mydisk` and remove `/mnt/mydisk`
- Create `${HOME}/mydisk` and mount `/dev/sda1` there (my boot/primary drive is `/dev/nvme0n1`)
- Update `/etc/fstab` entry and change to `${HOME}/mydisk`

FYI, I do not want to symlink. Bind is another option but so is this.

Comment: Technically, there's none. There's nothing unusual about mounting the drive in your home directory. It may lead to confusion if you use tools such as `du` and `ncdu` to recursively calculate total size of home directory (and you can exclude the other filesystems via `-x` flag to give accurate calculation). But for the system itself, no there's no obvious detriment

Comment: It should be fine.

Comment: Interesting. Why do not want to symlink?